# Network connectivity logs on OSX

Tags: networking, osx-lion, console, event-log

I'm trying to determine whether or not Macs store a log of network connectivity. Specifically, I'm trying to find out if one of my machines (Mac Tower, OSX 10.7.4, 2-2.26 GHz, 16 GB DDR3) lost connection to pinpoint an issue. This machine is on an external network where and the IT staff is not very helpful, so I'm trying to ensure that there were network issues rather than some other local issue on that particular machine.

Can you pull network logs thru Console that show when a network connection was established and was disconnected?

Answer (score 1):

`/var/log/system.log` (and the bzipped archives) should contain most of the stuff you need, for example:

```
grep en1 /var/log/system.log
```

Will return most information about `en1` - obviously replace this with whichever interface you're interested in.

If you want to go further in the past than the latest bit of the log, (use `head /var/log/system.log` to see how far back it goes) you'll need to look at the bzipped archives also in `/var/log/`.